# Does [NSStepper setMinimum/setMaximum] also set the value?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Given an NSStepper with a minimum/value/maximum already set, if I set the minimum to a valued between value and maximum, will the NSStepper's value change?

I know I could just try it, but that would only tell me for my current OS, and I can't find any documentation to indicate one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience (OS 10.5), NSStepper's value does indeed change if you set it's min to a value between value and max (or set the max to a value between min and value).  Like you, though, I could find no documentation stating this, so I'm not sure I'd rely on it.